# How to open .sql file at startup in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, startup

I'm looking to open specific .sql files that have multiple select statements on specific servers at startup in SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

For example, I want to open file *'EmQueries.sql'* when I open server **sqlemdata9**. When I open server **sqlplant2**, I would like to see file *'PlantQueries.sql'* open at startup.

How can I accomplish something like this?

Comment: seems like a bit of a strange question, why would you want to do something like this that can be achieved pretty simply without a fancy solution?

Comment: Because I work with multiple tables and servers everyday, so I figure if I can just open up pre-saved sql files at startup, then I don't have to do a lot of copying and pasting with SELECT statements.

Comment: you could create batch files to open management studio with specific files, but i think you'd still need to connect to the correct server manually

Comment: I see. I wasn't sure if there a simple solution to something like this seeing that I've never worked with batch files and management studio.

Comment: "ssms query.sql" command would open a file in ssms, but yeah, you still need to select server.

Comment: There is no such thing as "opening" a server. You connect to a server on Object Explorer, or you open a new query window with a specific connection. Your best option would be to create a Project (File > New > Project) and add your files to it. And/or add the servers you want to work with to `Registered Servers`.

Comment: Create an SSMS Project, add in all the .sql files you need to use, and then open that project when SSMS opens.

Comment: It is not automatic but you can double click a query and it will open connected to the correct server: In SSMS Create a Solution. Under the solution create a project for each server. Under the project create a connection and the queries that apply to that server. In your shortcut for SSMS add space and the solution name  "your_path\Ssms.exe" "your_path\solution.ssmssln" -nosplash

Answer (score 1):

You can  achieve the following procedure with Command Line Process, will help you connect to different databases related to specific files and user credentials.

This is Easy with command line **(cmd)**

```
ssms "C:\Users\Wizard\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\query.sql" -S ServerAddressOrIP -d Database -U Username -P Passwordhere
```

> Copy the following line to (.bat) batch file format and run it.